# which chemical element has the lowest boiling point?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

which chemical element has the lowest boiling point?

Is it Helium(He) or is it Hydrogen(H)?

Hydrogen is lighter than Helium.

Comment: Regardless of it is an element or a molecule,, helium has the lowest boiling point $(\pu{-269 ^\circ C})$. In comparison, hydrogen, which exists as a diatomic molecule, has the boiling point of $\pu{-253 ^\circ C}$.

Answer (score 4):

At its present form, this question is quite bad. I think you should've had a look at Wiki before asking this question. The boiling point of [Hydrogen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen) is around 20 K, while for [Helium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium), it's around 4 K. I don't memorize these. But, I had a dirty look at Wiki. If you want a reason for **why** it has...

Helium has a stablest $1s$ orbital, which has somewhat lower energy. And, this makes it chemically inert towards other elements and to other Helium atoms, which is also the reason for its lowest boiling point.

Comment: The low boiling point of Helium is due to its very weak interatomic forces. I don't think the reactivity of helium with other helium atoms has much of a role here. Apparently quantum effects also play an important role in the case of Helium due to its small size.

Comment: @kaliaden: I don't know much. That was just a guess though ;-)